# How to know type of Map value Map("key->"value") in Scala?

Tags: scala, reflection, type-variables

I have an issue with a value of Map("id"), its could have two types : String or Map[String,String].

```
Case 1: val a = Map("id" -> "123")
Case 2: val a = Map("id"-> Map("ide"->"abcd"))
```

I want to do a check with a Match case like this :

```
def d = a.get("id") match {

  case _:String => "String"
  case _:Map[String,Any] => "Map"


}
```

Does anyone have an idea of how should I handle this case??

Comment: Why in the name of types did you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sightly modified from Dmitry's answer. This code snippet uses `TypeTag` to [**Overcome *type erasure***](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20).

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeOf}

def d[T](map: Map[String, T])(implicit T: TypeTag[T]) = map.get("id") match {
  case Some(_) if T == typeOf[String] => "String"
  case Some(_) if T == typeOf[Map[String, String]] => "Map[String, String]"
  case Some(_) => "Other"
  case None => "Not found"
}

d(Map("id" -> "Hello")) // String.
d(Map("id" -> Map("Hello" -> "World"))) // Map[String, String].
d(Map("id" -> 10)) // Other.
d(Map("id" -> Map(10 -> true))) // Other.
d(Map.empty) // Not found.
```

Note, this will only work if all elements of the Map have the same type when the method is called...
If you have a `Map[String, Any]` in the first place, this becomes more complicated - and probably Dmitry answers would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost correct. Method `get` on the map returns an `Option`. All you need to do is wrap the values inside match. So you can do something like this:

```
val a1 = Map("id" -> "123")
val a2 = Map("id" -> Map("ide" -> "abcd"))
val a3 = Map("id" -> 42)

def d(map: Map[String, Any]) = map.get("id") match {
  case Some(_: String) => "String"
  case Some(_: Map[String,Any]) => "Map"
  case _ => "Other"

}

d(a1) // "String"
d(a2) // "Map"
d(a3) // "Other"
```

UPD: As @Luis pointed out because of type erasure second case will match any `Map`. See his answer if you want to match specific `Map`

Comment: Dmitry, be aware that due **type erasure** this will emit a compiler warning and that your second case will no only match `Map[String, Any]` but any `Map` (I would use `Some(_: Map[_, _])` to make it clear) - betty, if you are sure the nested map will always be a `Map[String, String]` then use this with a `.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]` if you need to perform more operations on the **map**. If not take a look to my answer.

Comment: This code will emit several warnings, because type erasure will result in inability to check that the nested map indeed has `String` and `Any` type arguments at runtime. If this is okay, and you understand the consequences, it is possible to mark the type parameters as `@unchecked`: `case Some(_: Map[String @unchecked, Any @unchecked])`, which would make warnings go away.